# Computing $\sup_{\Vert x-a\Vert\le r}{\Vert g(x-a)\Vert}$ where $g$ is a linear map.

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $E$ and $F$ two Banach space and $g:E\rightarrow F$ be a linear map. 
>   Denote $$f(x)=g(x-a),$$
>
> I would like to know if $f$ is tangent to $0$ at $a$  i.e. 
>   $$\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{m(r)}{r}=0$$ when $m(r)=\sup_{\Vert x-a\Vert\le r}{\Vert g(x-a)\Vert}.$

I am stuck to compute $m(r)$ here, I would say that it's $\Vert g\Vert \cdot r$.

Indeed, we have $\Vert g(x-a)\Vert_F\le\Vert A\Vert_{L(E,F)}\cdot \Vert u\Vert_E$. So, here I have $$m(r)\le\Vert g\Vert\cdot r.$$

*Question:* How can I continue the reasoning to prove that $m(r)=\Vert g\Vert \cdot r$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The result is not true. Let $E=F$ and $g$ the identity operator. Then $m(r)=r$.

Comment: But the norm of the identity operator is the identity right ? I don't understand why it's false.

Comment: Yes, the norm of the identity is $1$, and $m(r)/r=1\not\to0$. Consider $E=F=\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=x$. The graph of $g$ is not tangent to $0$ at $0$.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. In fact my question is more to prove that $m(r)=\Vert g\Vert\cdot r$ and then if $f$ is tangent to $0$ at $a$ in any case we need $\Vert g\Vert=0$ so $g$ is identically zero. :)